# Determine if CDF is valid

Tags: probability-theory

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the following function is a valid CDF:

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x< 0 \\
      1-ae^\frac{-x}{b} & x\ge0 
\end{cases}

Also, find the values of a and b such that the function above corresponds to the CDF of some
(a) Continuous Random Variable 
(b) Discrete Random Variable
(c) Mixed type Random Variable

For (a), I have used continuity property of CDF. This implies that at zero, left and right continuity is satisfied, $\implies 0=1-a \implies a=1$.

For (b), it should be only right continuous. So for any values of $a$ and $b$, it is a valid CDF?

For (c), I am not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cdf it should also hold that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to +\infty}} F_X(x)=1$, which is valid for all $b>0$.

- For a continues RV specifically, $X\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda=\frac 1b$, and as you correctly derived $a=1$.
- For the case where $X$ is discrete with a discontinuity at $x=0$ (which would be the only discontinuity), it should be $F_X(x)=1, \forall x\ge0 $, consequently $a=0$.
- For a mixed RV with a discontinuity at $x=0$, $$0<F_X(0)<1 \Rightarrow 0 < 1-a<1$$
  hence, $0< a<1$.